# Picture in Document

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    picture1 = new Image;
    picture1.src = "picture/loading.jpg";
    picture2 = new Image;
    picture2.src = "picture/loader.jpg";
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <a href="page5.html" onmouseover="document.picture2.src=picture2.src" 
                         onmouseout="document.picture1.src=picture1.src">
       <img name="picture" src="picture/loading.jpg" alt="image" />
    </a>
 
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

this is my code when i debug this it showing:

```
 Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.picture2' is null or not an object
```

But i already assign value to the 'document.picture2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global object is `window` not `document`. Therefore you may want to use `window.picture2.src` instead of `document.picture2.src`.

In addition, you should probably give a unique `id` to your elements and reference them using `document.getElementById()`:

```
<img id="picture1" src="picture/loading.jpg" alt="image" />
```

...is referenced using:

```
document.getElementById('picture1');
```

Comment: i got it i done mistake  the correct onmouseover and onmouseout is document.picture.src=picture1.src